# Can "allow for" mean "provide with", "make possible"?

Tags: meaning

Can "allow for" mean "provide with", "make possible"?

> This computer allows for complicated calculations. = provides us with
> the possibility to perform difficult calculations.
>
> That boat allows for taking up more than 20 people. = provides us with
> the possibility to accommodate more than 20 people on the boat.

Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in the examples given, "allow" = "provide" or "make possible".

Merriam-Webster shows "to make a possibility" for these examples.

In a close usage, "allow" may also means a constraint on what is possible.  Example:  "That boat allows 20 people" = provides the possibility of no more than 20 people.